# Visual Studio Code Run On Save Extension not running

Tags: visual-studio-code, save, workspace

I installed the Run On Save extension for VS Code. I made a Workspace setting for it, and if I change a file then resave, it does not seem to run. "I run for all files" does not show up in the console or terminal.

When I chose to edit the command configuration in my Workspace settings, it automatically edited the file with the comment "Place your settings in this file to overwrite default and user settings." so it looks like this:

```
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite default and user settings.
{
    "editor.mouseWheelZoom": false,
    "emeraldwalk.runonsave": {
        "commands": [
            {
                "match": ".*",
                "isAsync": true,
                "cmd": "echo 'I run for all files'"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm new to configuring Workspace settings, so I'm not sure if this is okay or not. I ensured that Run On Save is enabled by selecting it on the command palette.

Here is the site for the extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=emeraldwalk.RunOnSave

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the exact same issue.  I removed that extension and am using this one instead:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wk-j.save-and-run

It is a fork based on RunOnSave.  This one works for me when I set its configuration in my user settings and then run the command "Save and Run: Enable".

This one uses the bulit-in powershell terminal.

HTH

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing the same thing. It does the opposite order of Run On Save, but I got it to work for the most part.

Answer (score 31):

In order to see the console output, you have to be in the `Output` tab and select the `Run On Save` option in the dropdown. The extension was created before the integrated terminal existed and hasn't seen a major update in a while.

[image]

Regarding the comment that was added to your config:

> // Place your settings in this file to overwrite default and user
>   settings.

is unrelated to this particular extension. It is just `vscode` letting you know the purpose of the workspace level configuration. It allows you to override a subset of your more global user / default settings. This allows you to keep reasonable default preferences but to customize certain specific things in any given workspace.

Regarding the original `RunOnSave` extension, feel free to file an issue here https://github.com/emeraldwalk/vscode-runonsave/issues if you have any questions or problems. I would also welcome pull requests if anyone is interested.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to our dear @bingles, I have accidentally discovered that the commands should be added to `.vscode/settings.json` file instead of `.vscode/emeraldwalk.runonsave` as said in the [plugin documentation](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=emeraldwalk.RunOnSave#:%7E:text=Run%20On%20Save%20for%20Visual,don%27t%20trigger%20the%20commands.)

Add it to `settings.json` and everything should work as expected.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the extension to work on Workspace you must put the emeraldwalk.runonsave inside settings:

```json
    {
        "settings": {
            "emeraldwalk.runonsave": {
                "commands": [
                    {
                         "match": ".*",
                         "isAsync": true,
                         "cmd": "echo 'I run for all files'"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can use `code block` for `code section` that will make question/answer more readable and good. For more info you check this [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109)

Answer (score 0):

A related one:

Previously I used `RunOnSave`, this time around I used `Code Runner`.

> Code Runner - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner

Below are it's settings I used:

> File: %AppData%\Code\User\keybindings.json

```
{
    {
        "key": "ctrl+s",
        "command": "code-runner.run"
    }
}
```

> File: .vscode\settings.json

```
{
    "code-runner.saveFileBeforeRun": true,
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": [
        "code-runner.executorMap"
    ]
    "code-runner.executorMap": {
        "javascript": "node a.js"
    },
}
```

If possible, you could use Code Runner with the above settings, or use a similar to the above settings for the RunOnSave.

Note that RunOnSave has its own tab which is time-consuming to switch to another tab.

With Code Runner I can see the output in the Output tab itself which is a very nice thing, saves time.